# jQuery 'this' Looping through a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, this, each

I am trying to get the value of the current row's ID and the value of a selected radio button, which is a group in one of the cells, but has a unique name and no other radio buttons in the row.

It loops OK through the rows but I can not get the correct syntax to get the values, I am interested in.

On one occasion it looped through each 'TD' looking for an ID. on another it said .attr is not available for the 'this' object.

```
    function getWMarkImgs() {
       $('#wmkTable tr').each(function() {
       var v1 = $(this).tr.attr('id');
       var v2 = $(this input[name=group1]:checked).val();
       $('#dbgDIV').append('V1=' + v1 +' V2=' v2 + '<hr>');
    });
```

I always seem to have difficulty with the 'this' object.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getWMarkImgs() {
       $('#wmkTable tr').each(function() {
       var v1 = $(this).attr('id');
       var v2 = $(this).find("input[name=group1]:checked").val();
       $('#dbgDIV').append('V1=' + v1 +' V2=' v2 + '<hr>');
    });
```

OR

```
function getWMarkImgs() {
           $('#wmkTable tr').each(function() {
           var v1 = $(this).attr('id');
           var v2 = $(this).children().children("input[name=group1]:checked").val();
           $('#dbgDIV').append('V1=' + v1 +' V2=' v2 + '<hr>');
        });
```

OR(the best one)

```
function getWMarkImgs() {
           $('#wmkTable tr').each(function() {
           var v1 = this.id;
           var v2 = $(this).find("input[name=group1]:checked").val();
           $('#dbgDIV').append('V1=' + v1 +' V2=' v2 + '<hr>');
        });
```

Comment: +1 for just using `this.id`. Although any samples caching `$(this)` and then using `.attr('id')` are going to be negligibly close.

Comment: The third option `this.id` loops around 5 times the number of td elements in the table row + the tr itself.

Comment: The second option also loops and the V2 does not work. Output `V1=undefined V2=undefined
V1=P1040001 V2=undefined
V1=undefined V2=undefined
V1=undefined V2=undefined
V1=undefined V2=undefined`  But the V2 in the third option did work.  On each row I only have one ID and that is the TR element.

Comment: what do you mean by bullshit loop.create a jsfiddle for your problem

Comment: It is looping.  The problem is caused by my having a separate TABLE in one of the cells of the row.  So I need to somehow identify the primary row for my each loop and decide which one of the above I prefer.  Any pointers on how to isolate the Primary row. Thanks anyway - I have learnt something.

Comment: Solved.  I added a Class to my main table TRs and then did `$('#wmkTable tr.rowMain').each(function() {`  Many thanks again for everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

try [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

```
function getWMarkImgs() {
   $('#wmkTable tr').each(function() {
      var v1 = $(this).attr('id');
      var v2 = $(this).find("input[name=group1]:checked").val();
      $('#dbgDIV').append('V1=' + v1 +' V2=' v2 + '<hr>');
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function getWMarkImgs() {
    var div = $('#dbgDIV');
    $('#wmkTable tr:has(input[name=group1]:checked)').each(function() {
        var me = $(this);
        var v2 = me.find('input[name=group1]').val();
        div.append('V1=' + me.attr('id') +' V2=' v2 + '<hr>');
});
```